# Window.Current.Content is getting null in winui3

Tags: winui-3, winui

Window.Current.Content is getting null in winui3
Gettting exception object reference not set to an instance
I am implementing Ishitestvisible
Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

As per the `Window.Current` documentation:

> For UWP apps, gets the window of the current thread. **Desktop apps always return null**.

https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.window.current

Comment: Very strange that their WinUI3 docs say to use it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/basics/navigate-between-two-pages

Comment: @JohnGlen The doc you linked is a part of the Windows app design basics content, none of which is limited to talking about WinUI 3 development. 

The steps above actually state: "In the left pane of the New Project dialog box, choose the Visual C# > Windows > Universal or the Visual C++ > Windows > Universal node." indicating it was written in the days of UWP.